# Parse out part of URL using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to parse out a part of URL using regex operation. This might be old question. But I am new to regex and searched so much for my requirement and not able to find it. I know ParseURL can be used here. But my URLs are not properly structured to use that. Suppose my URL is as follows,

```
url = https://www.sitename.com/&q=To+Be+Parsed+out&oq=Dont+Need+to+be+parsed
```

Here I want to find out when &q= occurs and parse out until & occurs next. I want to remove + or any special characters in the middle. The output should be,

```
To Be Parsed out
```

Also if there is no match, the original URL should be returned.

I have tried the following,

```
re.search('q=?([^&]+)&',url).group(0)
```

this returns,

```
&q=To+Be+Parsed+out&oq=Dont+Need+to+be+parsed
```

Can anybody help me in parsing this out. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.search()` to get the desired substring and then replace all `+` with spaces with `str.replace()`:

```
re.search(r'/&q=([^&]*)', url).group(1).replace('+', ' ')
```

- `re.search(r'/&q=([^&]*)', url).group(1)` gets the desired portion and `replace('+', ' ')` does the replaements

**Example:**

```
In [56]: url
Out[56]: 'https://www.sitename.com/&q=To+Be+Parsed+out&oq=Dont+Need+to+be+parsed'

In [57]: re.search(r'/&q=([^&]*)', url).group(1).replace('+', ' ')
Out[57]: 'To Be Parsed out'
```

---

In case when there is no match, catch the `AttributeError` exception raised by `re.search.group()` e.g.:

```
try:
    out = re.search(r'/&q=([^&]*)', url).group(1).replace('+', ' ')
except AttributeError:
    ## No match, do what you want
```

Comment: This works fine. In some scenarios, when we can't find a pattern, it throws an error. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'. Can we write a condition to return the URL when we can't find a pattern?